# jquery append html show hide in IE

Tags: jquery, html, hide, append, show

I need help with displaying images from a MySQL database.
What I have is a an Dynamic PHP/HTML table that has multiple pages with a pagination link.
The table layout is: Book Title, Author, Publisher, Category and image.
I can connect to database with connection script - working OK.
I can see all the information for the table at the correct column and row per above locations including the images.
At this point I hover over the link below the thumbnail image and use jQuery to pop up a larger view of the thumbnail, this works in all
browsers except for Internet Explorer.

First I connect to Database with a connection script.
This is the code I use to query database:

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
 $bg = ($bg=='#ffffff' ? '#FCFCFC' : '#ffffff'); // Switch the background color. 
 echo '<tr bgcolor="' . $bg . '">
 <td id="books">' . '<h4>'. $row['booktitle'] .'</h4>'. '</td>
 <td id="auth">' . $row['author'] . '</td>
 <td id="publ">' . $row['publisher'] . '</td>
 <td id="cat">' . $row['category'] . '</td>
 <!--<td id="isbn">' . $row['isbn'] . '</td>--> 
 <td id="img">'.'<img src="'. $row['image'].'" width="90"/>'.'<div span="getLargeImage">'.'<a href="'. $row['image'].'" class="popup">Larger view</a>'.'</span>'.'</td>
</tr>';
```

here is the jQuery script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.popup').hover(function(e) {
        var getId = $(this).attr("id");
        var getAttr = $(this).attr("href"); 
        var html = '<div id="full_img">';
        html += '<img src="'+ getAttr +' "/>';
        html += '</div>';
        //console.log(getId);
        //console.log(getAttr); 
        $('body').append(html).children('#full_img').hide().fadeIn(100);
        $('#full_img').animate({"width" : "0px","width" : "250px"}, 100);
        $('#full_img').css('top', e.pageY + -330).css('left', e.pageX - 350);

    }, function() {

        $('#full_img').animate({"width" : "250px","width" : "0px"}, 100);
        $('#full_img').fadeOut(10);
        $('#full_img').remove();  
    });

});
```

As I said above the jQuery hover/show larger image works works in all browsers except for Internet Explorer.
to see how it is working at this point surf to:

http://stevenjsteele.com/database/php/index.php

any help would be appreciated.
thanks
ussteele

Comment: The link to your demo isn't working - I get a 404 error.

Comment: In the script on your website you are missing the ending quote (") for the image source: `html +=    '<img src="'+ getAttr +'"/>';`

Comment: Also, just an advice: **never have duplicate id's in your html** (each row has a `#img` td). Most javascript frameworks, like jQuery rely on the native browser implementation for performance, and these implementations may vary (usually they return just the first element found top-to-bottom, but that is not guaranteed).  Instead of id, consider using a class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like I said in the comment - on your website you have a missing quote in the line:

```
html += '<img src="'+ getAttr +'" />';
```

See this working [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/danmana/jGVxk/)

Comment: This is copied from view source:

Comment: html +=    '<img src="'+ getAttr +' "/>';

Comment: It wasn't like that when I first accessed the site. Now, with the ending `"` it works in IE8 for me.(btw: What version of IE ?)

Comment: Win XP SP3: IE 7 and MAC OS X Win XP SP3 IE 8